# Why does my iPhone flash when I receive a message?

Tags: iphone

After the recent iOS upgrade, my iPhone flashes every time I receive a text message, and I can't find a way to turn it off. I checked the setting but there are no options where I can disable it from flashing. It is very annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a feature introduced with the **[iOS 5 update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1456)**.

> Accessibility improvements:
>
> - **Option to light LED flash** on incoming calls and alerts for iPhone 4S and iPhone 4
> - **Custom vibration patterns** for incoming calls on iPhone
> - New interface for using iOS with mobility-impairment input devices
> - Option to speak a selection of text
> - Custom element labeling for VoiceOver

You can change the setting in **Settings** -> **General** -> **Accessibility** options:

[image]

Comment: Why is the L-----+----R slider filled in on the left hand side? This makes no sense....

Comment: @adolfgarlic Hey, that's a really interesting question! I never thought about that. My guess is that it's probably easier to instantly grasp where the dot it. Without the blue line you only have a whiteishgrey circle on a whiteishgrey background. You should post this as a question on http://ux.stackexchange.com. (ux <-> user experience). If you don't want to, I will ;)

Comment: Also why do you have to press on the slider buttons (like the custom vib and LED flash ones) this confused the carp out of me when I first got an iphone trying to slide the darn things over...